# How Do I Define Imported Maven Project in Intellij

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have opened an existing Maven project in Intellij.  Under "Project Structure -> Artifacts" the pane is empty.  When I click the + sign to add one, it chooses "unnamed.war".

How can I get it to generate the artifactId and version as defined in the pom?  I must be missing a step here.

[image]

Comment: in the Maven Projects toolbar, click on "Reimport all projects"

Comment: Thanks.  Same thing.  I "Reimport All Maven Projects", but I still only get "unnamed" as shown above.

Comment: Artifacts should be created automatically when you import the Maven project. Try to import it again using the New Project wizard. If it doesn't work, file a bug at http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/IDEA with the sample project attached.

Comment: Please past the groupId / artifact /version portion of your pom.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is important to understand how you created the project.  Did you choose "Import project from external model"?  If you simply opened an IntelliJ project that someone else created, then I would suggest creating a new project using the "Import project from external model" as this should properly build your dependencies and outputs correctly.